# JQuery Tabs To Create DropDown Menu :Help Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown navigation with Jquery Tabs. My problem is finding a way to hide the default open panel. I want the dropdown to show only when I hover it or click. I can't find a good way. Help is needed.
HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Faculties</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">New Courses</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1"  >
    <table cellpadding="10" id="table1">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
     <table cellpadding="10">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
    <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tabs").tabs({
    event:'mouseover',      
 });
});
```

Thanks, guys

Answer (score 0):

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tabs").tabs({
    event:'mouseover',   
     collapsible: true, active: false
 });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8101/)

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tabs-1').hide();
      $('#tabs').mouseover(function(){
            $('#tabs-1').show();
      }).mouseout(function(){
            $('#tabs-1').hide();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code from jsfiddle, that I created

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5j3xtdo1/1)

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Faculties</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">New Courses</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab" id="tabs-1"  >
    <table cellpadding="10" id="table1">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div class="tab" id="tabs-2">
     <table cellpadding="10">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div class="tab" id="tabs-3">
    <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Science</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Biology</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Government</a></td>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
        //alert(this)
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.tab').not(id).slideUp();
        $(id).slideToggle();      
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tab{
     display:none;
}
```